# VeeValidate 3.1 how to add rules on external file vs in each component

Tags: vee-validate

I am able to use the rules fine but I have to have them in each component, which is not DRY and just cluttered. I would like to add `rules.js` file for validation, but in the file you just extend a class so I am unsure how to implement this in terms of exporting and importing the file into the components, or making them global, which I would like to do since I have many many forms in the application.

If it were a variable I could import it but I am drawing a blank on how to import these rules that extend `vee-validate`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a `vee-validate.js` file:

```js
import { extend } from "vee-validate";
import { required } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";

// Install rules
extend("required", required);
```

Import that file in your entry file, typically `main.js` if you are using `vue-cli`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import './vee-validate';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Or if you are using `Nuxt.js`, create a `plugins/vee-validate` with the same contents and add it to `nuxt.config.js` plugins array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fine. if `this.$validate` is off, then we can't use `this.$validate.$validatorAll()`,  what will be the perfect solution here. Because I had something like this working in version 2 but doesn't work anymore.

```
 this.$validator
    .validateAll("scope")
    .then(result => {
      if (!result) {
        alert("error");
        return;
      }
      alert("success");
    })
    .catch(() => {});
```

Well, after reading some few things I managed to make it work this way;

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-use-veevalidate-3-for-form-validation-bb18e9c3256c

1. In your bootstrapper js file or in your plugin file or probably where you are kickstarting your javascript; Example: `index.js`.

   ```
   import Vue from "vue";
   import { ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate";
   import { ValidationObserver } from "vee-validate";
   import * as VeeValidate from "vee-validate";

   // Now tell vue to use this plugin

   Vue.use(VeeValidate, { inject: false });
   Vue.component("ValidationProvider", ValidationProvider);
   Vue.component("ValidationObserver", ValidationObserver);
   ```

Note: For those who are using nuxt.js. you can copy and paste this☝️code in your `root directory`, `plugins/vee-validate.js`. And get into your nuxt.config.js file which is also in your `root directory`; and add the file to your plugins like so:

```
   plugins: ["...some existing plugin", "@/plugins/vee-validate.js"],
```

2. In your form, this is what you have to do. I am using [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) for my forms but also applies to a regular bootstrap form as well.

   ```
     <ValidationObserver ref="observer" v-slot="{ invalid }">

         <form class="pt-3" @submit.prevent="sendDataToServer">
           <ValidationProvider name="email" rules="required|email" v-slot="{ errors }">

             <b-form-group  class="{'has-danger': errors[0]"} label="Enter your email" label-for="email" :invalid-feedback="validateFeedback">
              <b-form-input type="email" id="email" name="email" v-model="form.email" data-vv-scope
                aria-describedby="input-1-live-feedback" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter Email" trim required></b-form-input>

              <p class="invalid-form" id="input-1-live-feedback">{{ errors[0]}</p>
             </b-form-group>

         </ValidationProvider>
      </form>
   ```
3. Lastly in your computed and methods:

   ```
    computed: {
      validateFeedback() {
        Object.keys(rules).forEach(rule => {
          extend(rule, {
          ...rules[rule], // copies rule configuration
          message: messages[rule] // assign message
       });
     });
   }
   },

   methods: {
      /** Send login form data to server */
      sendDataToServer() {
         const isValideForm = this.$refs.observer.validate();
          if (!isValideForm) {
              return false;
          }
       console.log("working... ");
      }
   }
   ```

Hoping this helps someone.